# Open new JFrame when clicking/selecting an item from the combo-box (Java)

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe, jcombobox

I want to create a GUI in which the combo-box allows me to open a new JFrame by pressing an item from the combo-box. Any ideas on how could I dot that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of that, how about you use an appropriate layout manager (e.g. [`CardLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html))? This will enable you to easily toggle views within the same container.

Comment: I have never used CardLayout until now. I'll see what I can do.

Comment: For another example, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5786005/418556).  See also [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554636/the-use-of-multiple-jframes-good-bad-practice/9554657#9554657) for links to two answers with many other alternatives suited to different use-cases.

Answer (score 2):

Add an `ActionListener` to the `JComboBox`:

```
JComboBox combo = new ...
combo.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    // This code runs when an item is selected in the combo.
    JFrame frm = new ...
    frm.setVisible(true);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Add an event listener to the comboBox and just handle the event to generate a new JFrame